# Сортировка списка словорей по ключу python

Tags: python

Есть список словарей:

```
[
    {
        "object": "apple", <<<
        "count": 10
    },
    {
        "object": "banana",
        "count": 11
    },
    {
        "object": "apple", <<<
        "count": 5
    }
]
```

Теперь мы хотим изменить последовательность списка так, чтобы рядом стояли словари, в которых значение ключа `"object"` совпадает:

```
[
    {
        "object": "apple", <<< 
        "count": 10
    },
    {
        "object": "apple", <<<
        "count": 5
    },
    {
        "object": "banana",
        "count": 11
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` с соответствующим ключом:

```
lst = [
    {
        "object": "apple",
        "count": 10
    },
    {
        "object": "banana",
        "count": 11
    },
    {
        "object": "apple",
        "count": 5
    }
]

lst.sort(key=lambda x: x['object'])
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'object': 'apple', 'count': 10},
 {'object': 'apple', 'count': 5},
 {'object': 'banana', 'count': 11}]
```